# Can't install Server tools with SSIS on top of Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-express, ssis

I have a SQL Server Express edition with management studio and i'm trying to use the enterprise disks ("SQL Server 2005" Enterprise Edition 32-bit Server Applications") and I can't get it to give me the option of installing the server components or a server instance. What am I missing?

Comment: I posted an answer, but this question is probably better asked at ServerFault.com.  If my answer is not what you're looking for I'd recommend you try your question there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install the server tools for Enterprise edition because you need to actually install the server version. You can't add enterprise tools to the Express edition.  You need a brand new installation of the full blown Enterprise edition.

If you want the server tools, you need to install the right version, meaning in your case, the Enterprise edition.  I don't know if you can do it side-by-side as a new instance (and I'm not even sure if you can install it on a non-server version of Windows.)

**Edit**

I found the answer to the question of whether you can install it in a non-server version of Windows [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

**End Edit**

However, if you mean the CLIENT side tools, so that you can create SSIS packages for a SQL Server on another machine (meaning a true server), without having to have Enterprise edition on your development pc, see [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6102265.html).